# ¿Palabra para designar el odio hacia los discapacitados mentales?

Tags: definiciones

¡Hola! Me preguntaba si había alguna palabra para definir el odio hacia los discapacitados mentales, ignorantes o gente con algún déficit o trastorno de memoria. Por ejemplo:

`Él odia cuando digo una estupidez, entonces él es un *****.`

`Creo que he acosado a muchos ignorantes, entonces soy *****.`

Answer (score 1):

La palabra es:

OLIGOFRENOFOBIA

Se obtiene con:

Oligo (ὀλίγος): Poco

Frenos (φρήν): Inteligencia

Fobia (φόβος): Odio/Desprecio (Igual que con la homofobia)

Su abreviatura es (OFF OligoFrenoFobia)

Comment: Dos resultados me salen en Google y ninguno es en español. No parece un término muy usado. Y eso de que el inglés americano es el idioma universal decirlo en un sitio sobre el idioma español, la segunda lengua más hablada en el mundo no está bonito.

Comment: @RubioRic estoy de acuerdo contigo. Por claridad quiero añadir que somos más los que hablamos español como idioma nativo que los que hablan inglés.  Aqui dos fuentes https://www.vistawide.com/languages/top_30_languages.htm  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers

Comment: Excelente palabra Oligofrenofobia....+1